# Sequentially injecting and running jQuery in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, inject

The following injects jQuery into Chrome Developer Tools.

```
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type
jQuery.noConflict();
```

---

Though it works well, my goal is to sequentially run jQuery afterwards without having to separate the code.

I have tried:

```
setTimeout(function(){
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
}, 2000);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Result: *Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined*.

Running that a second time is successful.

---

That said, my next attempt was:

```
setTimeout(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
}, 1000);
jQuery.noConflict();
}, 2000);
```

Result: *Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined*.

Running that a second time is successful.

---

What can I do to make the delay work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's something like this:

```js
const jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.onload = () => {
  jQuery.noConflict();
};
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(jq);
```

Set `.onload` (or however you want to set your `load` event handler) before setting `.src` as some browsers don't actually need `script` to be part of the document and will load as soon as `.src` is set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to add a $("#randomID") in the mix so it also registers without erroring with same error message?

Comment: @Mech Note that `jQuery.noConflict()` only resets the `$` variable (it has an option that tells it to also reset the `jQuery` variable, but that's not used here). Any jQuery stuff can still be called using `jQuery` instead of `$` as in `jQuery("#randomID")`.

Comment: When adding `jQuery("#randomID")` to the end or within the `.onload`, it unfortunately does not load within the same block of code. I feel this may need to be submitted as another question however.

Comment: It would need to be within the `load` handler. And it does work in my tests so I'd have to assume something else is wrong. Do you have a pre-existing element with an `id` attribute set to "randomID"? Are you doing anything with the results of `jQuery("#randomID")`?